# MS SQL - Separating tables to another file or filegroup

Tags: sql-server

On the MSSQL database there are some custom created log tables and they have constraints. They hold the 90 percent of the all data on database. I try to separate these tables to another file(ndf) so when i backup the database i am able to exclude these files(or filegroup)

I confused that should i create 2nd datafile on Primary(default) filegroup to move tables or create custom filegroup and file. Can i use EF Core

I have read this document :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-files-and-filegroups?view=sql-server-2017

**It's written:**

- Secondary data files are optional, are user-defined, and store user
  data.

**Also Recommend:**

- If you use multiple data files, create a second filegroup for the
  additional file and make that filegroup the default filegroup

Comment: Tables are stored on filegroups, not files. A filegroup can have multiple files, but if you want to direct a table to a new file, it must live on a separate filegroup.

Comment: How good is your backup strategy if you are excluding 90% of the data???

Comment: Custom Log data' are important. So we are going to move them to another disk but they have also contraints with another tables on db. Log's Disk has own backup procedure so we dont need to care db backup of those files.

Comment: How good is your data security strategy if 90% of your storage is consumed by custom logging? I think you have more than one architectural question you should be asking yourself.

Comment: @EricBrandt Custom Log tables' data dont hold any sensitive data about db accounts, transactions etc. It is not about MSSQL Log tables. Why would i think about security strategy? Beside all of them it is not real world production database

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the external backup procedure for this data if that's your thought. Or, rather, try doing a restore of it to make sure you can do what you think you can do.